# Qi wireless charger

Tags: samsung, wireless-charging

I just purchased a Samsung Galaxy S9+ and it should arrive soon.  I am interested in getting a couple wireless chargers and looked on Amazon.  I see there are a large variety of chargers.  Since this will be my first wireless charging phone, I was curious, are there any specific features and specifications I need to look for in a Qi charger for my phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, congratulations on your phone. Once you start using wireless charging you'll be hooked.

I have Samsung's own [EP-PG950 wireless charger](http://www.samsung.com/sg/mobile-accessories/wireless-charger-stand-convertible-pg950/EP-PG950BBEGWW/) that was marketed alongside last year's S8 and S8+. That supports two modes of charging:

1. **Normal wireless charging**, at 5V and 2A input (i.e. 10W input) and 5V and 1A output (i.e. 5W output)
2. **Fast wireless charging**, at 9V and 1.67A input (i.e. 15W input) and 9V and 1A output (i.e. 9W output)

Samsung's flagships support both normal and fast wireless charging.

Now, the Qi standard itself specifies a minimum of 5W output (i.e. the *normal wireless charging* listed above), so any Qi charger will support your phone.

If you stick to brand name Qi chargers (e.g. Samsung itself, or Belkin, Anker, and other such big names in the mobile accessory space), you will be fine.

Comment: I bought a cheap $10 charger from Amazon a day or two after I got the phone.  It said it supported the S8, so I figured it would work.  It works great.  Its good to know about the fast charging though.  I will look to see how much more expensive they are.  If the cost is significantly more, Ill still with the cheap ones.